# Windows Batch Script Get Current Drive name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which is on a usb key. I need to know the drive name the batch is in.

Example, if it's E:\mybatch.bat it should find E:\ same thing for F:\, G:\ etc.. when it's opened.

How could I do that in batch script. (Windows)

Comment: Do you want the drive where the batch is located or the drive of the current working directory? Those two are distinct.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`%CD%` is what you're looking for.  It prints the current working directory of the batch file or command running it.  If your batch file is on the root of the drive, it will just print the drive letter, otherwise you'll have to parse the first 2 characters.

Example:

```
echo %CD%
```

prints

```
E:\
```

on a flash drive mounted to E:.

Update:  As Andriy said in the comments, if you are just looking for the first three characters of the path, then use this instead of %CD%:

```
%CD:~0,3%
```

This will result in `E:\`, for example, anywhere on the drive.

Comment: I'm trying to configure the geany editor to compile my java file even if im on usb. I used %CD%JDK\bin\javac "%f" but it didn't work. Anyways your answer is perfect and I will accept your answer as soon as i can. ty

Comment: try %CD%\ instead of just %CD%.  Otherwise itll look for E:JDK\bin\javac instead of E:\JDK\bin\javac

Comment: I did a simple script,
`code`
@echo off
echo %CD%
pause
`code`
printed C:\ not C:

Comment: oops, you're right.  if you're not in the root directory, the forward slash isn't there, but if you are it is.  m'bad

Comment: `%CD:~0,2%` evaluates just to the [current] drive letter and ':'. Accordingly, `%CD:~0,3%` additionally includes '\'.

Comment: Using `%__CD__%`, you always get the backslash at the end

Comment: Be VERY careful with using %cd%. It is the folder the program _is executing from_, _not_ the folder the program is _in_. Windows mangles the run path if you drag and drop a file onto a script or exe to give it as argument to that program. WinXP makes it run from the "c:\Documents and Settings\username" folder, and Win7 uses the dropped argument file's path instead. You should use %~d0% and %~p0% for the batch file's drive and location.

Comment: I've submitted an edit highlighting Nyerguds' important distinction, and included a link to another answer addressing the second thing that was asked by the OP.

Comment: ...and since that edit was rejected, I've submitted [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58604805/4877269) highlighting the two different things that have been asked in the question.

Answer (score 27):

M$ documentation "[Using batch parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call#batch-parameters)" says:

> Modifier: %~d0
>
> Description: Expands %0 to a drive letter.

Comment: When calling a batch-file with Elevated Rights, THIS is the RIGHT one to use!

Comment: Reference link is dead as of the current time of this comment.  Potential optional link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call

Answer (score 13):

## Beware

The existing answers to this question don't acknowledge that the question is actually asking about two different things:

1. the drive of the **current working directory** (*“Get Current Drive name”*); and
2. the drive of the **batch file** (*“I need to know the drive name the batch is in”*).

These can be different when the batch file is started from a working directory other than its residing location.  Readers should therefore be clear on the difference before determining which solution is relevant to their case.

## Drive of the **current working directory**

```
%CD:~0,2%
```

This takes the full current working directory and trims it down to the first two characters, which will be a drive letter and a colon, e.g. `C:`.

## Drive of the **batch file itself**

```
%~d0
```

This trims the full path of the batch file (in `%0`) to just a drive letter and a colon, e.g. `C:`.

---

*(this is an expanded version of my [rejected edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24413115) to [Kai K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14499141/4877269))*

Comment: The correct syntax is `%~dp0` without the trailing percent sign

Comment: Thanks, @jeb—removed the spurious `%` sign.  Left it as `%~d0` rather than `%~dp0` though, because in this case we don't want the path.

Answer (score 9):

If run from inside a .CMD/.BAT file, you can use `%~dp0` to get the current/working directory. This one is a little safer as it is aware of UNC paths and such. Reference for the syntax of that variable is available [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Comment: Not true @ewall : parameter 0 always retains the directory of the batch file location - which may not be the current working directory if someone called the batch file from another drive.  Even calling a batch file with a fully qualified pathname does not change the current working directory to that path.   This is why %cd% is useful - it shows the current working directory, not the batch file location.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all USB drive letters from any drive with this.

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>NUL`) do (

  if %%l equ 2 (
    echo %%i is a USB drive.
  )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Very Much @Sparky3489, if I have just one USB Flash Drive, I put this within your Algorithm, Right After the

```
echo %%i is a USB drive.
Set FlashDrive=%%I
```

I also changed the Wording of the Identifier to

```
Echo %%i is a USB Flash Drive~!
```

Then, After, {and Outside} the Algorithm, I can add the Flash Drive Path such as...

```
Set FlashPath=%FlashDrive%\Users\Public\Documents
```

Then by setting up other Paths
Such as

```
Set SourcePath=C:\Users\Public\Documents
```

I can make an Batch File BackUp For the Flash Drive, (can be Called Via Windows Short-Cut with an Associated Icon in your Quick Launch Window ~ Search "Quick Launch", if in Doubt to what I'm Talking About).

```
Rem  * * * * * * * * * Start Batch File * * * * * * * * * *
@Echo OFF
cls
Echo FlashDrive UpDater for
Echo.
Echo Excel, Word ...
Echo * * * * * * * * * ~ Excel SpreadSheets ~ * * * * * * * * *
XCopy /D /I /V /Y /U /S "%SourcePath%\Excel Documents\*.*" "%FlashPath%\Excel Documents\"
Echo * * * * * * * * * ~ Word Documents ~ * * * * * * * * *
XCopy /D /I /V /Y /U /S "%SourcePath%\Word Documents\*.*" "%FlashPath%\Word Documents\"
Echo.
Echo.
Echo FlashDrive = %FlashDrive%
Echo FlashPath = %FlashPath%
Echo.
Echo * Bonus Switch Info * * * * *
Echo * XCopy Switch  /D ~ Copies Files Changed On or After the Specified Date.
Echo *          {If no Date is Given, Copies only those Files whose
Echo *          Source Time is Newer than the Destination Time}.
Echo * XCopy Switch  /I ~ Copies More than One File to Destination (Assumes Destination is a Directory)
Echo * XCopy Switch  /S ~ Copies Directories and Subdirectories Except Empty Ones
Echo * XCopy Switch  /V ~ Verifies Each New File.
Echo * XCopy Switch  /U ~ Copies only Files that Already Exist in Destination.
Echo * XCopy Switch  /Y ~ Suppresses Prompting to Confirm You Want to Overwrite an Existing Destination File.
Echo.
Rem for More Info on XCopy Switches GoTo http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128756
Echo Directory Path = %~DP0
Echo.
Echo * Batch File Name = %0 *
Echo.
Rem Echo %CD:~0,2%, {Returns "Drive Letter & Colon"}
Rem Echo %CD:~0,3%, {Returns "Drive Letter & Colon & BackSlash"}
Pause
cls
Pause
Exit
Rem  * * * * * * * * * End Batch File * * * * * * * * * *
```

Answer (score -1):

```
%CD:~0,2%
```

This will give you the current drive in the format  `C:` , i.e. first 2 chars from the current working directory

```
C:\Users\ashish>ECHO %CD:~0,2%
C:

D:\projects>ECHO %CD:~0,2%
D:

D:\projects>ECHO %CD%
D:\projects
```

Comment: same as the accepted answer from 2011 - sans the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Like others have said `%~d0`

There's no point in going over that again, but if you have stumbled into this thread then this will cd to the directory of the batch file.

```
@echo off
set "fullDir=C:\Program Files"
cd /d %fullDir%                                &rem changes to the full directory 'C:\Program Files'.
echo You're now cd' in the '%cd%' directory.
pause
```

Also if you want to run a batch file from another drive such as `Z:` then this one will do that.

```
cd /d %~d0                                     &rem Changes to the current directory
echo You're now cd' in the '%cd%' directory.   &rem This is now your full path of the batch file cd' into.
pause
```